# Como colocar o EditText no meio da tela?

Tags: android, android-layout

Usei `Gravity.CENTER`, o que centralizou o texto no EditText e não o EditText na Activity.

```
package com.example.wbsoftware.testetcc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout layout;
    private EditText[] vetorEdits;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("qtd", 0);
        vetorEdits = new EditText[count];


        for(int i=0; i<count; i++){

            vetorEdits[i] = new EditText(Main2Activity.this);
            vetorEdits[i].setHint("Periodo " + (i+1));
            vetorEdits[i].setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            vetorEdits[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            vetorEdits[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


            layout.addView(vetorEdits[i], new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300,150));


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você chama `vetorEdits[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` , você está centralizando apenas o conteúdo do `EditText`

Para centralizar o próprio `EditText` em relação ao `LinearLayout`, você deve fazer o seguinte

```
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Dessa maneira, você determina que os elementos dentro do `LinearLayout` devem ser centralizados

Comment: Obrigado, consegui!

Comment: @Hacker Se a resposta do regmoraes resolveu o seu problema, marque a resposta dele como correta.